# Search for unpublished note on Magnetic Monopole Detection

Tags: experimental-physics, specific-reference, magnetic-monopoles

**Design of an electromagnetic detector for Dirac monopoles** by Luis Alvarez

This is an unpublished 1963 note from Lawrence Radiation Laboratory (Physics Note 470), and is heavily cited in all papers on magnetic monopole detection. Does anyone have a scanned copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, Luis Alvarez was famous for his notes/memos, and Lawrence Berkeley Laboratory (the successor name for the Radiation Laboratory) has been kind enough to put them all online at [Alvarez Physics Memos](http://alvarezphysicsmemos.lbl.gov/memo.html). Search for memo 470 and you will get a pdf back that includes 'Design of an Electromagnetic Detector for Dirac Monopoles'. The 10 in that pdf are a fascinating mixture and worth glancing through. I am afraid to download any more or else I might spend the rest of the day (and weekend) looking through them...